# Help with a deciphering command with telnetd in it

Tags: shell-script, telnet, bourne-shell

Help with deciphering commands

`[ $1 -ge 20 ] && telnetd -p 233 -l /bin/sh`

I know **/bin/sh** is a Bourne shell and telnetd is a telnet daemon but I'm not sure how they work together.  I think someone tried to leave a back door open but I'm not sure what / how the other commands work together.

Thanks

Comment: Can you check the man page of telnetd? The [page I know](https://linux.die.net/man/8/telnetd) does not document the -p and -l options.

Comment: I checked to but couldn't find anything about it.  I think I'll just delete it if anything breaks I'll come back to it.  But I really had no idea what [ $1 -ge 20 ]  was trying to do either.

Comment: The `[ ... ]` clause checks if the first argument to a shell script is greater or equal 20. The code after `&&` is executed if the code before it returns `true`. It's a shortcut for `if [ $1 -ge 20 ]; then telnetd ...; fi`.

Comment: What flavor of Unix is this from? The use of `telnetd` (deprecated decades ago in favor of `sshd` in the civilized world) points at some prehistoric system...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the context of [FreshTomato](https://wiki.freshtomato.org/doku.php/buttons_led), what the command does is, if the variable $1 is greater or equal to 20, then run a `telnet` daemon on port 233 that will drop you inside a shell.

```
[ $1 -ge 20 ] && telnetd -p 233 -l /bin/sh
```

- `$1` is the number of seconds the SES/WPS/AOSS button has been pressed
- `-p` is the port number
- `-l` to listen
- `/bin/sh` the command to run when a connection is established

So, if you press that button for more than twenty seconds, go to another host and do:

```
telnet myFreshTomatoHost 233
```

You'll be taken straight to the shell. It is meant as a procedure to open a backdoor if you have physical access to the system running FreshTomato.

Comment: Thanks!!........